# Prefixing route controllers

Tags: laravel-4

I've two route controllers within a route group:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::controller('dashboard/', 'DashboardController');
    Route::controller('dashboard/profile', 'DashboardProfileController');
});
```

That works until I add prefix key to the array:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'dashboard', 'before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::controller('/', 'DashboardController');
    Route::controller('/profile', 'DashboardProfileController');
});
```

It's weird as the first route controller works since I can access `localhost/dashboard` but the second fails on `localhost/dashboard/profile` and or `localhost/dashboard/profile/edit`

What's wrong here?!

Comment: Try to remove slash before `profile`: Route::controller('profile', 'DashboardProfileController');

Comment: @cheelahim I did it already but didn't change anything.

Comment: Put profile controller first.

Comment: @cheelahim Add your comment as an answer. I'm going to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems both of them route to one location, therefore the longest one should go first because it is interpreted as argument.

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'dashboard', 'before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::controller('/profile', 'DashboardProfileController');
    Route::controller('/', 'DashboardController');
});
```